# Chrome Extension: How do I make sure I'm only requesting the minimum permissions I need?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There's an obvious temptation to request the maximum permissions from users who install my Chrome Extension simply because it makes development easier knowing that whatever Chrome API I use is covered.

But is there an easy way to know I'm only requesting the minimum permissions I need?

Comment: It depends on what your extension does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no automated way to figure this out, but if you want to do it manually, use the following procedure:

- Deny everything.
- Then, selectively request only what is needed to make a specific feature work.
- Work through your extension, feature by feature.

In the end you will have only requested what is actually needed, and not more.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed that might have been the case. Nice opportunity for someone to make something that scans your source for mentions of APIs and lists the minimum permissions